# Format new parition of drive with xfs version 4 in Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partition, xfs, mkfs

I am working on an arcade machine and it cannot be updated unfortunately. A drive has corrupted data on it and in order to delete it I need to re-partition that drive. (I know it's the data and not the drive because I have used dd to clone the partition onto another drive and the data can still not be removed with rm -rf /folder)

In order to fix this I need to do mkfs.xfs but I need to set the version. When just using mkfs.xfs it sets it to 5 automatically.

Reading though the documentation on mkfs.xfs I see no way to change the version. https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-mkfs.xfs/

I am looking any solutions, I can use slax, ubuntu or redhat to solve this. (I currently have machines with all 3)

**xfs_db> version**

`[0x20a4+0x0] = V4,NLINK,ALIGN,DIRV2`

**xfs_info**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyNCS.png

**Linux Kernal** is 2.4.23

This machine also cannot use SATA because it does not have SATA drivers.  If anyone knows how to manually install those, that would also be a big help.

---

***UPDATE***

I found a version of SLAX that is 6.1.2.  It also does not have SATA Support, but the biggest issue is when I use fdisk and mkfs.xfs on this version then the UBUNTU can (newest version) can no longer read the partition type of the disk, but... it can read the partition type of the disk straight from the arcade machine.

***UPDATE 2***

Ubuntu 10.04 is quite easy to find, Ubuntu still hosts it.  You can find an older version and use this to get it to format drives to XFS V4 but... for my project its still not working.

Comment: Exactly how ancient is the OS? And _what_ is the OS?

Comment: Some version of linux.  Kernel... 2.4.23 something.  Its for an In the Groove arcade machine.  I checked everywhere a brand new should be and all I can find is the kernel.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't even have SATA support.

Comment: can you paste complete output of `xfs_db> version` and `xfs_info <mount point>` and your kernel version where you are trying?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WYMLKJh.png
Version is listed in the post itself.  Info and version are in this image however.

Comment: Most likely you'll need to go way back and find a contemporary version of Linux. Assuming the old kernel doesn't understand a modern XFS filesystem.

Comment: If you were able to clone the data out (sucessfully?) is the goal to move it back? You can wipe, and reimage without knowing the underlying data in most cases...

Comment: I have several goals.  1.  I would like to make a permanent back up.   2.  I would like to wipe the (in this case) /sda5/  and put the data back on sda5.  I am still having a lot of trouble with that, I have a few more tricks I am going to try.  Basically I need to try to use mksf.xfs on the SLAX 6.1.2 after I clone the entire drive again.    Is there a way with DD to just clone the partition filesystem and not the data?

Comment: "I know it's the data and not the drive because I have used dd to clone the partition onto another drive and the data can still not be removed with rm -rf /folder" - But if you have data structure issues with the filesystem on that disk, those problems would be replicated by `dd` as well. You should use `smartctl -a /disk/path` to check the disk before assuming it's fine. The data got corrupted somehow, and an even mildly failing disk is always a good place to start with blame.

Comment: I'll give that a go Spooler, thank you.